# Vue Ref nolonger reactive after being returned from composable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am working with Nuxt 3 composition API using the Vue 3 script setup syntactic sugar.

I have an issue where refs from my composable isn't reactive once it has been returned to a component. Watching the value has no effect.

Take note that I am using VueUse to create different instances of the filedialog (useFileDialog).

```
import { useFileDialog } from '@vueuse/core'
import { ref as storageRef, getStorage, listAll, getDownloadURL, deleteObject } from 'firebase/storage'
import { useStorageFile } from 'vuefire'
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'

export const useFileUpload = (props) => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const filename = ref();
    const fileRef = ref(null);
    const selectedImages = ref([]);
    const images = ref({});
    const imagePreviews = computed(() => {
        if (images.value) {
            return Array.from(images.value).map(file => URL.createObjectURL(file));
        }
        return [];
    })

    const {
        url,
        uploadTask,
        upload,
    } = useStorageFile(fileRef)

    const { files, open } = useFileDialog()
    const { open: openMaterialer, files: materialerFiles } = useFileDialog();
    const { open: openPlantegning, files: plantegningFiles } = useFileDialog();

    watch(files, (newFiles) => {
        if (newFiles.length > 0) {
            const fileType = newFiles[0].type.split('/')[0]
            if (fileType === 'image') {
                images.value = newFiles
            }
            else return
        }
    })

    const uploadFile = async () => {
// Some upload logic here
}
        

    watchEffect(() => {
        // Confirms reactivity in composable
        console.log('materialerFiles in upload:', materialerFiles.value);
      });

    return {
        imagePreviews,
        files,
        materialerFiles,
        plantegningFiles,
        uploadTask,
        open,
        openMaterialer,
        openPlantegning,
        uploadFile,
    };
};
```

Now in my component i use the composable (remember that the composable is auto imported)

```
    // files
    const { files, materialerFiles, plantegningFiles } = useFileUpload()
    
    // Watch for changes to materialerFiles
    watch(materialerFiles, (newMaterialerFiles) => {
      console.log('changed')
        userInput.value = {
            ...userInput.value,
            materialerFiles: newMaterialerFiles,
        };
    });
```

This should log 'changed' to the console from the component. But nothing happens.

Have i misunderstood something or is this a known issue. Any workarounds or suggestions?

I expect to log the files which should materilaerFiles should contain.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a composable in the "composable" directory
2. Import useFileDialog from vueUse and ref,watch, computed from vue
3. Inside the composable create 3 instances of the fileDialog
4. Return the reactive file values from the composable
5. in a component deconstruct the composable const {returned values here} = useYourComposable()
6. Watch for changes in one or more of the returned values

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Probably something that is specific to autoimports. There's absolutely no difference if watch is called inside custom composable or outside it, it's just JS function without magical properties.

Comment: Explicitly importing the composable does not change the result.

Comment: Please, provide a demo. I expect that it won't be possible to reproduce with the provided steps for the reason mentioned above. Notice that the difference is that watchEffect runs immediately and watch doesn't. In case there was 'materialerFiles in upload' but not 'changed', that's why

Comment: There is no difference in behavior when switching watchEffect out with a normalt watch or the other way around. I get the same result. Working on the demo

Comment: As far as I can tell the issue lies with the composable from VueUse. All refs i create myself change reactively as expected. But specifically the values deconstructed from usefileDialog does not react to changes once imported in a component

Comment: The implementation is simple, i see no clue why this would be the case https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useFileDialog/index.ts . It may be the case where does watch and watchEffect are imported from. If `vue` package has been duped somewhere in the deps, it could be a problem, but I don't see how this would cause this exact behaviour. That you rely on autoimports adds additional points of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the issue.

The issue lies in my misunderstanding of how composables work.

In my codebase I have a component which uses my composable to set the files, and another component where I wanted to use the composable to import the files which were set in the first component. This does not work due to the nature of how composables work.

In short, the issue was:

**Scope of Composable Invocation:**

When you invoke useYourComposable() in ComponentOne.vue, and useYourComposable() in ComponentTwo.vue, two separate instances of the composable are created. Each instance has its own separate state. Changes to state in one instance won't affect the same state in the other instance.

**The solution:**

In order to share state between different components, you'd have to use a state management solution. Someting like Pinia or Vuex (Pinia is the new standard for Vue3).

Comment: Or use module-level state in the composable, if it makes sense for it. AKA a "singleton" composable.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes do you have any examples of this? I had ran into a similar problem

Comment: @mjbates7 You simply hoist state variables out of the composable function to the composable's module's top-level. The way you initialize stuff does have to change a little, but otherwise that's about it. It's the poor man's store; if you are only managing a little state and don't need Pinia's other features, you can simply make a composable that returns a reactive object.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are setting a ref in userInput.value.materialerFiles, not the value of newMaterialerFiles ref.

Try update you watch by setting userInput.value using the value of materialerFiles ref like this:

```
// files
const { files, materialerFiles, plantegningFiles } = useFileUpload()

// Watch for changes to materialerFiles
watch(materialerFiles, (newMaterialerFiles) => {
  console.log('changed')
    userInput.value = {
        ...userInput.value,
        materialerFiles: newMaterialerFiles.value,
    };
});
```

Comment: I get what you're getting at but for that to work, the watch function would need to actually log 'changed' to the console. If it doesn't, where I'm setting the ref won't matter.